# Invoke JS function after PHP foreach

Tags: php, foreach, echo

I have a `foreach` for a function called `send_msg`. At the end of the loop, I want to run a JS function. I thought that maybe counting in the loop and then doing an echo would be the right way to go. Below is what I have tried.

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($user_ids);
foreach(array_column($user_ids, 'user_id') as $user_N) {
    send_msg($user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);   
    if ($i == $len - 1) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">showDiv();</script>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You realise all the PHP code will execute before anything runs in the browser? You can put your `<script>` block anywhere

Answer (score 2):

My friend,

You have to understand that `PHP` is server-side language. It handles your actual data processing from your database. It has nothing to do with your client-side operations.

so let PHP Code execute the way it wants to be -

Then write your whole client-side code.

Consider the short snippet.

```
<?php 

$i = 0; $flag = false;
$len = count($user_ids);
foreach(array_column($user_ids, 'user_id') as $user_N) {
 send_msg($user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);   
 $i++;
}
$flag = true;
?>
<html>
  ...
 <div></div>
 <script>
 var flag = '<?php echo $flag; ?>';
 if(flag=='true' || flag == true){
   //-----your script code ----
 }
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: What's with `$flag`? The only thing it appears you should be checking for is `$len > 0`, eg `var flag = <?= json_encode($len > 0) ?>;`

Comment: @Phil : The `$flag` is only for understanding purpose for the user, he seems to be beginner with `PHP`. But your code is much correct. Thank you

Comment: But it's pointless. You might as well set it to `true` initially and therefore, not set it at all. Anyway, good answer but given OP's code won't add the `<script>` if there are no iterable elements, you should at least be checking for that

Comment: @Phil: I updated my answer, Your code seems much better and cleaner. Thank you